When do I not need to use h1-h6 headers to create emphasised text
Can I use syntax such as
<span class="subheader-uline">My custom emphasised text</span>

without contravening accessibility rules (WCAG)? I don't intend this custom header to be navigated via screen readers; it's purely aesthetic.
I tried to use this syntax and it's flagged as illegal in accessibility stating I should use a h1 - h6 tag, which I don't want to do.

Why you don't want to?
When you use h3 is obvious you have a header, and html will give you some styling (lay outing) out of the box.
When using span you need customization to achieve the same result and customization often leads to unnecessary technical debt.

@Andre, thats the whole point i dont want h1-h6 styling, i want to  style this as i please. The string "subheader-uline" does not matter to screen-readers; i could call it "cheese-sandwhich" if i wanted. Its text that i want to style as i want with an underline/overline etc

It seems weird that any text would be purely aesthetic. Could you provide the actual contents so that we better understand? If it’s something like ASCII art, role="img" might be appropriate. If it’s visible, you shouldn’t hide it away from AT.

Could you add what checker flags this and what its error message is? (Does it detect font size and use that as evidence that the text should be a heading?)

You can try to use the aria-hidden to hide non-interactive content from the accessibility API.
<span class="subheader-uline" aria-hidden="true">My custom emphasised txt</span>


Ok, yes thats a solution, this has come about because i read on W3C docs that h1-h6 should not be used for subheadings and was trying to do the right thing.

Be careful because aria-hidden completely removes the text for screen readers and other assistive tools, for example for dyslexia or voice control. That's probably not what you really want.

Maybe I misunderstood the question. I suggest you follow the instructions below from @QuentinC

I can't delete this post because it is an accepted answer. @nelle, can you remove the check this post as an accepted answer?

Usage or not of H1-H6 shouldn't depends on aesthetic, or if you want or not to have that element navigated by screen readers.
It should only depends on the natural meaning of the text, which is commonly called semantics.
Is it an heading ? If yes, you should use H1-H6. If it isn't a heading but rather some emphasized text, you shouldn't use H1-H6 but more appropriate elements such as strong or em.
Determining if your text is a heading or not should be obvious, normally.
Aesthetic should never dictate which element to use, since you can always do what you want in CSS:
Similarly, you shouldn't assume that the element is useless for screen reader users and shouldn't be included in screen reader navigation.
If it's really a heading, it's necessarily important enough to be included in navigation. If you don't feel it to be important enough, probably that it isn't really a heading.
IN short, it should be an all-or-nothing. Whether it's a heading, goes with the associated aesthetic/layout, and it implies appearing in navigation and table of contents. Or it isn't a heading, it doesn't appear in any navigation, and you shouldn't fake the aesthetic to make it appear as a heading visually.
It isn't uncommon to add supplementary headings not displayed on screen especially made for screen readers to help in navigation, but the opposite just sounds wrong.

It is not clear why the code <span class="subheader-uline">My custom emphasised text</span> would be flagged as an accessibility violation. The following points may help.

If the text is not a heading, then not using heading markup is the right decision. Screen reader users rely on correctly marked up headings to navigate the page, so heading markup should reflect page structure and not be abused to make text larger.
If the code example is part of a paragraph, then using a span element is fine (but more on emphasis below). However, if it is a paragraph, a p element would be the right choice. Screen readers have shortcuts to jump to the next paragraph, e.g. NVDA has Ctrl + down arrow to speak the next paragraph.
If the sort of emphasis you want to convey is based on "strong importance, seriousness, or urgency", then the strong element should be preferred. If you just want to signal emphasis or stress when the content would be spoken, then you can use the em element. You can still add a class attribute to add your own styles.

